# android: unable to build project error: Cannot read packageName from

Tags: java, android, build

i'm new at android development, i just changed my pc, i copied android project from old one and pasted in new pc, Not Exported project as zip file :'( ,
when i open the project in android studio (new pc) i got following error,

> Cannot read packageName from F:\ZahraUniversity\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:667)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:136)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:261)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
>       at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
>       at 
>       at blah blah blah

I don't know what is happening i already tried other answers, everyone is saying to edit manifest file but my project does not contain any manifest in (app\src\main)
This is how my project app folder looks like
[Project app folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP0Yt.png)

I don't know what is wrong with it, please help i'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a manifest file, you need to create one.

Quoting from the official docs:

> **Every app project must have an AndroidManifest.xml file** (with precisely that name) at the root of the project source set. The manifest file describes essential information about your app to the Android build tools, the Android operating system, and Google Play.

[App Manifest Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

Comment: i just copied this project working project from another pc, and i don't think i need to create another manifest.xml file right?

Comment: You said that your project doesn't contain a manifest in app/src/main but it should. If you say "another manifest.xml file", does that mean that you have one? Where is it?

Comment: Yeah i know that my project should contain manifest.xml file but there is not, i don't know what is happening, Ahhh.

Comment: Yeah i know that my project should contain manifest.xml file but there is not, i don't know what is happening, Ahhh.